# GNU/Linux: sound recording has electric hum

Tags: linux, audio, audio-recording

I can record sound from my microphone, but I get an loud electric hum at around 20% of the max level. This is no matter what software I use to record.

How can I get rid of that noise?

Soundcard: Analog Devices AD1984A

The only dials in alsamixer that change recording levels are Capture, Digital and Internal (which is hardlinked to another Internal). They all boost volume of both audio and noise.

The best config so far is: Capture 65, Digital 55, Internal 0 - and unplugging power supply(!) and head phones(!).

[image: alsamixer]

Comment: I wonder if its the microphone, or some other interference instead. If its hardware there's very little you can do

Answer (score 1):

Try running `alsamixer` and looking for any channels that are cranked up to the max.

Hit F5 (display all channels) and then use the left and right arrow keys to move between the channels, and up/down to adjust their levels.

While doing this, keep an eye on Audacity's recording volume monitoring meter. To quit alsamixer, hit escape.

Often I find a channel that doesn't appear in the GUI mixer in Gnome which is blowing out my recording.

Comment: Great advice. My recording channel was maxed out, indicated by red at the top of the levels bar. Thanks Nate from Kalamazoo!